# Matlab: Selectable text in EPS-figures when using latex interpreter and/or importing fonts

Tags: matlab, latex, interpreter

I would like to save figure as EPS-files with a special font. I can do that with latex as interpreter, but that also means the text in the EPS figures are no longer selectable or searchable, which I want it to be.

Is there any way to get around this?

What I am doing right now is this:
(But I am doing it for about a hundred figures, so I do not want a special manual and time-consuming solution)

```
% Choose fontname and interpreter to be set to everything it applies to
setfontname = ('Adobe Garamond Pro');
setinterpreter = ('latex');

% Change all interpreters from tex to latex. 
list_factory = fieldnames(get(groot,'factory'));
index_interpreter = find(contains(list_factory,'Interpreter'));
for i = 1:length(index_interpreter)
    default_name = strrep(list_factory{index_interpreter(i)},'factory','default');
    set(groot, default_name,setinterpreter);
end

% Set all fontnames to the right font
set(groot,'DefaultAxesFontName', setfontname)
set(groot,'defaultUicontrolFontName', setfontname,'defaultUitableFontName', setfontname,'defaultAxesFontName', setfontname,'defaultTextFontName', setfontname,'defaultUipanelFontName', setfontname)
clabelfont = setfontname;
clabelinterpreter = (setinterpreter);

% Set some data
ix = [0 50 100 140];
rpmx = [0 1000/6 1000/3 500 2000/3 5000/6 1000];
Qw = [  0  0     0     0
        0  2.97  4.04  4.91
        0  7.60 10.92 13.16
        0 12.46 17.45 21.02
        0 17.56 25.64 30.58
        0 24.92 34.42 41.92
        0 28.48 41.30 49.57];

% Make the figure
close all
figure('Position', [500, 100, 250, 250])
[C,h] = contourf(ix,rpmx,Qw,[0 1 5 10 15 20 25 30 40],'ShowText','on');
xlabel('Current [A]')
ylabel('Speed [rpm]')
title('Core losses [W]')
caxis([0 40])
clabel(C,h,'FontName',clabelfont,'interpreter',clabelinterpreter)

% Save the EPS
print(['forstackof'],'-depsc')
```